# truffle migration take so long time and show deployment failed after 750seconds

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle

### Deploying 'Migrations'

> transaction hash:    0xf7ca748e0645cf1c9b06d9f0fac3d20fefb95245a464af132e7f21290b49a2a1
> *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined! -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode)..

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

i want to deploy contract on ropsten test network through infura